# Facebook JS SDK share to managed page

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

Facebook is a bit of a black box to me, but I believe I've followed the advice on SO and elsewhere, however I still can't get this to work.

**EDITED CODE based on proposed answer**:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  var login;
   window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'Valid_App_ID',
      status     : true,
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.2'
    });

     FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
          login = response;
            console.log('Hello ' + response.name);
        });
    } else {
        //login cancelled or not every permission accepted
    }
}, {scope: 'manage_pages, publish_actions'}); 

function fb_share() {
    FB.ui( {
        method: 'feed',
        name: login.name,
        link: 'valid_URL',
        picture: 'valid_image_URL',
        caption: 'some_text',
        to: valid_page_ID
    }, function( response ) {
        console.log(response);
    } );

}
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.share-btn').on( 'click', fb_share );
});
       };
</script>
```

In practice, the link, picture and caption fields are filled in from user inputs, and the `to` field is completed automatically based on the `name` (so that it is always a page managed by the logged in user).

I have used myself as the test (added as a 'role' to the app settings), and have granted permission to the additional items in the scope of the log-in.  I can successfully post to my personal timeline by commenting out the `to:` line in the FB_share function, but if I leave that line in, even though the page_ID is for a page I manage, I get an error message in the console (and in the share dialog):

`Object {error_code: 100, error_msg: "Cannot post to a user who has not installed the application."}`

I'm sure I missing something simple, but from what I've read, the code above should work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Thanks for any advice.

Comment: The variable `login` is the response data from the login.  I've tried with `login.id` and `login.name`, but it makes no difference.  `login.first_name` is there only because that's what I'd rather have displayed on the shared post.  I'll correct the code above.

Comment: Are you using `localhost`?

Comment: No - I've loaded the page on a website.

Comment: Do you have the correct `appId`? Are you logged on to Facebook already?

Comment: Yes, and yes - I received the correct login and permission request (accepted) and can share to my own profile.

Answer (score 0):

All code, besides the self-executing function that imbeds the proper `<script>` tag, needs to be run inside `window.fbAsyncInit = function(){ /* in here */}` after `FB.init()`.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
  FB.init({
    appId: 'valid_App_ID',
    status: true,
    xfbml: true,
    version: 'v2.2'
  });
  FB.login(function(response){
    if(response.authResponse){
      FB.api('/me', function(apiResp){
        // remember asyc is asyc
        $('.share-btn').click(function(){
          FB.ui({
            method: 'feed',
            name: apiResp.first_name,
            link: 'valid_URL',
            picture: 'vaild_image_URL',
            caption: 'some_text',
            to: 'Facebook_Page_ID'
            }, function(uiResp){
              console.log(uiResp);
            }
          });
        });
      });
    }
    else{
      // redirect to facebook url to app loggin
    }
  }, {scope: 'manage_pages, publish_actions'});
}
(function(d, s, id){
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if(d.getElementById(id)){return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  // if running from localhost add protocol like https:
  js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
})(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk');
```

Comment: I've moved the self executing code to the top and placed all code inside  the `fbAsyncInit` function, but the result is the same.  I'll edit the new code above.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, I followed this almost exactly (just moved the self executing code to the top and removed an extra `}`) and added in the basic code to get the value of the various inputs to populate the elements in `FB.ui` - and same result (error message as above).  I have confirmed the app ID is accurate, my FB ID is added as a 'role' on the app, the page ID is definitely a page for which I have admin access, and I have granted permission for both extended permissions in the `scope`.  If I run `FB.api('/me/accounts', function(apiResp){ console.log(apiResp);` I can see the page.

Comment: If I run `FB.api('/me/permissions', function(apiResp){ console.log(apiResp);`, both the extended permissions are listed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `FB.ui` approach (above) was lacking an access token, and I couldn't find any way to add it.  The following code (which relies on the Graph API) works (differently, but OK).  The `.go` click function is required in case the browser blocks pop ups.  Then, after the `FB.login` function, FB.api gives access to users' pages which are looped to get their number and name for a drop down selector.  Clicking the `.share-btn` then retrieves the correct page id and access token and passes them to a second call of the FB.api function which posts the message.  What this approach misses is the UI aspect of the previous code, where the proposed post is displayed in a pop up with post options.  I haven't been able to find any way to replicate that yet.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
  FB.init({
    appId: 'Valid_App_ID',
    status: true,
    xfbml: true,
    version: 'v2.2'
  });

  $('.go').click(function(){

  FB.login(function(response){
    if(response.authResponse){
     FB.api('/me/accounts', function(apiResp){
        console.log(apiResp);
        for (var i = 0; i < apiResp.data.length; i++) {
        $('#select').append('<option value = ' + i + '>' + apiResp.data[i].name + '</option>');
        }
        $('.share-btn').click(function(){
            var n = $('#select').val();
            var to = apiResp.data[n].id + '/feed?access_token=' + apiResp.data[n].access_token;
            FB.api(to, 'post', {message: message}, function(response) {
            console.log(response);
          });
        });
      });
    }
    else{
      // redirect to facebook url to app login
    }
 }, {scope: 'manage_pages, publish_actions'});

  });

}
```